# Searching for a regular expression in Eclipse (finding all links without an onclick attribute)

Tags: regex, eclipse, file, search

I am trying to create a proper regular expression to find all anchors in my project with Eclipse File Search.

What I'm looking for:

```
<a href="some.url" onclick="some onclickHandler">
```

What I want to accomplish is finding all anchors without an onclick and add it when needed.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex `<a href="\S+"((?!onclick).)*>`. It will find all links without the onclick pattern.

Short explanation for the interesting part `((?!onclick).)*`: `?!onclick` is a [Zero-width negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html). This means the regex engine will match if it does not contain the word onclick. The surrounding `(` and `.)*` tells the regex engine, that the onclick exlusion can be surrounded by any other character.